# access 'opener' class object from another object

Tags: php

I have the following code snippet:

```
class A
{
    public function greeting(){echo "Hello from A";}
    public function goodbye(){echo "Bye bye from A";}
    public function open()
    {
        $obj_b = new B();
        $obj_b->close_message();
    }

}

class B
{
    public function greeting(){echo "Hello from B";}
    public function close_message()
    {
        //get the 'opener' class object and access method goodbye() 

    }
}

$obj_a=new A();
$obj_a->greeting();
$obj_a->open();
```

So Class A and B have no inheritence defined and all methods are not static. 
An object from Class B is opened within a Class A object. What I am trying to achieve is for $obj_b to accesss the 'opener' class and execute the goodbye() method.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

**From A**

```
$obj_b->close_message($this);
```

---

**From B**

```
public function close_message($obj){
    $obj->goodbye();
}
```